# Snap on flashlight lockout mode

Tags: tools, lights

I'm looking into a snap-on light, and it features a "lockout mode".

Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: A link or picture or part number or something would be nice? Further this is not an automotive question.

Answer (score 2):

On Snap-On flashlights lockout mode is when you hold the on button down for three seconds and turns the flashlight off and it is locked.

This is feature is to prevent the light from getting turned on if you have it in a carrier that get's banged around.  Your batteries won't get wasted by accidentally turning the light on.  It's a nice feature.  Other manufacturers offer it as well.